# verb form of "obvious"

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives

Is there a verb form of the adjective *obvious* and if so, what is it?

Comment: What is a word that means "to make something obvious" --  is what the question is about, right?

Comment: *Explain* (make something clear), *expose* (bring out something into the open), *reveal* (disclose) can all work depending on the context. There is probably an even better word. Let's see what the others have to say meanwhile.

Comment: Do you have a specific meaning in mind, or are you just looking for *any* verb that's cognate with *obvious*? If the latter, then: *obviate* (meaning "remove; avoid, prevent").

Comment: @ruakh Is *obviate* being cognate with *obvious* make it work with the same meaning?

Comment: indeed I wanna say, I hope that I obvious my question to you. is that correct?

Comment: No, "I obvious my question to you" is not used in English, nor is there a verb form of _obvious_ that will work in the sentence you give in the comment immediately preceding this one.  Your two most likely options are to add _make_ to the sentence (either as  "I make obvious my question to you" or as "I make my question obvious to you") or to replace _obvious_ with an entirely different verb such as _clarify_ ("I clarify my question to you").

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Kris, there are several single words which you could use, but their appropriateness depends on the context.

However, the simplest and most common verb form of "obvious" is **"to make obvious"**:

> The desert was a dangerous place - this was *made obvious* by the many bleached bones lying half-buried in the shifting sands.

Comment: I don't think that "to make obvious" is simpler or more common than "to be obvious".